# Data Storage - how to calculate data storage

Tags: sales-cloud

Would like to know how's the calculation work for data storage entitlement for below org license setup.

Salesforce platform = 1000 license
Salesforce = 20 license

Answer (score 2):

From [Data and File Storage Limits documentation:](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=limits_storage_allocation.htm&type=0)

> **For data storage, Contact Manager, Group, Professional, Enterprise, Performance, and Unlimited Editions are allocated the greater of 1 GB or a per-user limit.** For example, a Professional Edition org with 10 users receives 1 GB, because 10 users multiplied by 20 MB per user is 200 MB, which is less than the 1 GB minimum. A Professional Edition org with 100 users receives more than the 1 GB minimum, because 100 users multiplied by 20 MB per user is 2,000 MB.

Answer (score 0):

In your case it is going to be the salesforce license only I think, so
20*20MB = 400MB.